# Указание наследования при рекурсивном обходе

Tags: ооп, delphi, delphi-7, рекурсия, сериализация

Есть код класса папки и файла (т.к. нужно их различать), унаследованных oт TComponent, код рекурсивного обхода папки. Как выполнить создание соответсвующих объектов с учетом наследования (проблема в указании наследования), т.е. для каждого объекта указать владелец в конструкторе Create, что в перспективе даст возможность сериализации потомков с использованием процедуры GetChildren. В коде есть массив объектов TComponent, так вот необходимо нужным образом запоминать индексы родителей (Owner) и потомков для наследования. Код прилагаю ниже

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses  
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,  
  Dialogs;

type  
  TForm1 = class(TForm)  
  private  
    { Private declarations }  
  public  
    { Public declarations }  
  end;  
  Tfolder=class(TComponent)  
  private  
    { Private declarations }  
  FPath : string;  
  FName : string;  
  FComponent : TComponent;  
  public  
    { Public declarations }  
  procedure SetFName(var Name: string);  
  function GetFName : string;  
  procedure SetFPath(var Path: string);  
  function GetFPath : string;  
  protected  
     { Protected declarations }  
     procedure GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent); override;  
     procedure SetParentComponent (Value: TComponent); override;  
  published  
     { Published declarations }  
  property Path : string read FPath write FPath;  
  property Name : string read FName write FName;  
  end;  
  TFile=class(TComponent)  
 private  
    { Private declarations }  
  FPath : string;  
  FName : string;  
  FSize : integer;  
  public  
    { Public declarations }  
  procedure SetFName(var Name: string);  
  function GetFName : string;  
  procedure SetFPath(var Path: string);  
  function GetFPath : string;  
  procedure SetFSize(var Size: integer);  
  function GetFSize : integer;  
  protected  
     { Protected declarations }  
     procedure GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent); override;  
     procedure SetParentComponent (Value: TComponent); override;  
  published  
     { Published declarations }  
  property Path : string read FPath write FPath;  
  property Name : string read FName write FName;  
  property Size : integer read FSize write Fsize;  
  end;  
  var  
  Form1: TForm1;  
  ArrTfolder[200] : Tfolder;//массивы создаваемых объектов    
  ArrTfile[200] : Tfile;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tfolder.SetFName(var Name : string);  
begin  
  FName:=Name;  
end;

function Tfolder.GetFName : string;  
begin  
  Result:=FName;  
end;

procedure Tfolder.SetFPath(var Path : string);  
begin  
  FPath:=Path;  
end;

function Tfolder.GetFPath : string;  
begin  
  Result:=FPath;  
end;  
procedure TFile.SetFName(var Name : string);  
begin  
  FName:=Name;  
end;

function TFile.GetFName : string;  
begin  
  Result:=FName;  
end;

procedure TFile.SetFPath(var Path : string);  
begin  
  FPath:=Path;  
end;

function TFile.GetFPath : string;  
begin  
  Result:=FPath;  
end;

procedure TFile.SetFSize(var Size : integer);  
begin  
  FSize:=Size;  
end;

function TFile.GetFSize : integer;  
begin  
  Result:=FSize;  
end;

procedure Tfolder.GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent);  
var I: integer;  
OwnedComponent : TComponent;  
begin  
  inherited GetChildren(Proc, Root);  
  if Root = Self then  
    for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do  
    begin  
      OwnedComponent := Components[I];  
      if not OwnedComponent.HasParent then Proc(OwnedComponent);  
    end;  
end;

procedure Tfolder.SetParentComponent (Value: TComponent);  
begin

end;

procedure TFile.GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent);  
var I: integer;  
OwnedComponent : TComponent;  
begin  
  inherited GetChildren(Proc, Root);  
  if Root = Self then  
    for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do  
    begin  
      OwnedComponent := Components[I];  
      if not OwnedComponent.HasParent then Proc(OwnedComponent);  
    end;  
end;

procedure TFile.SetParentComponent (Value: TComponent);  
begin

end;

procedure FindFiles(const DirPath: string; Str: TStrings);  
var  
SR: TSearchRec;  
begin  
if FindFirst(DirPath + '\*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then  
try  
  repeat  
  if not ((SR.Name = '.') or (SR.Name = '..')) then  
      begin  
          if SR.Attr = faDirectory then  
            FindFiles(DirPath + '\' + SR.Name, Str)  
          else  
             Str.Add(SR.Name);  
      end;  
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0;  
  finally  
    FindClose(SR);  
end;  
end;  
end.
```

Comment: > Необходимо осуществить создание

Необходимо - осуществите. А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Что-то как-то через Альпы.
Во-первых, два класса не нужно, тем более что у них одни и те же методы и свойства. Достаточно одного TFile.
Во-вторых, нужно построить алгоритм заполнения (создания компонент по структуре файлов), входная точка нужна. Пока ее нет.
В-третьих, parent (или Owner - что там нужно, задача не очень понятна) заполнять во время обхода директории. Т.е. создаем ребенка и сразу ему назначаем parent.

Сформулируйте задачу подробно, что в итоге с этими компонентами будете делать и зачем нужны именно TComponent.

Comment: вопрос подредактирован

Comment: Как я понимаю, в процедуру FindFiles надо добавить

    ArrTfolder[0].Create(nil);
    ArrTfolder[0].SetFPath("D:\Root"); // допустим путь к корневому каталогу D:\Root
    ArrTfolder[0].SetFName("Root");

Это насчет входной точки (комментарий к (1 час назад) Yura Ivanov), а вот как с наследованием и индексами наследуемых элементов?

Answer (score 1):

Сократим лишние сущности:

```
TFile=class(TComponent)  
private  
  FPath  : String;  
  FSize  : Int64;  
  FParent: TFile;
published  
  property Parent: TFile read FParent write FParent;
  property Path  : String read FPath write FPath;
  property Size  : Int64 read FSize write Fsize;  
end;

procedure FindFiles(const DirPath: string; parent: TFile; Owner: TComponent);
var  
  SR: TSearchRec;
  mfile: TFile;
begin  
  if FindFirst(DirPath + '\*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then  
    try  
    repeat  
      if not ((SR.Name = '.') or (SR.Name = '..')) then  
      begin  
        mfile:=TFile.Create(Owner);
        mfile.Path:=DirPath+ '\' + SR.Name;
        mfile.Size:=SR.Size;
        mfile.Parent:=parent;//Это новое свойство в TFile
        if SR.Attr = faDirectory then  
          FindFiles(DirPath + '\' + SR.Name, mfile, Owner);
      end;  
    until FindNext(SR) <> 0;  
  finally  
    FindClose(SR);  
  end;  
end;

procedure TForm1.MagicButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FindFiles('D:\',nil,Self);
end;
```

Итак, файлы превратились в компоненты. Зачем это нужно?